# Best practice to redirect Laravel home to another URL?

Tags: redirect, routes, laravel-authentication, laravel-7

How I can redirect the Laravel 7 auth home URL to the dashboard.

**My route filE route/web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;    

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('/home');
})->middleware('auth');
```

**MyLogin Controller seems like this**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;    
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending a few hours on this I found the below solutions

Just Make Changes in app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

To

```
public const DASHBOARD = '/dashboard';
```

Then make small changes in another files i.e app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

To

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::DASHBOARD;
```

Make a final change in app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

To

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::PARTNERS);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Change your rout to

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/dashboard');    
})->middleware('auth');
```

Not open the CMD and inside the project folder and run the command `php artisan optmize:clear`  and check now by the login.

Comment: No need to change the constant `HOME` to `DASHBOARD`, just change the value from `/home` to `/dashboard`. And for the default root route, just use the constant `HOME`, as in `return redirect(App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::HOME);`

Answer (score 0):

So simple solution is :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;    

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```